# Autocomplete on ruby on rails for elasticsearch not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, elasticsearch, jquery-autocomplete, tire

I am trying to implement autocomplete on my RoR application but I am unable to figure out a way to get the output.

I have a table univ which I indexed as universities the mapping for the index is as follows

```
tire do
  index_name 'universities'
  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :rank, type: 'integer'
    indexes :univ_name, :analyzer => 'keyword', :boost => 10
    indexes :location, :type => 'string'
    indexes :state, :type => 'string'
    indexes :state_id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :grade_rate, type: 'integer'
    indexes :attendance, type: 'integer'
    indexes :description
  end
end

def self.univ_name_matches(term)
  tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page]) do
    query {string "univ_name:#{term}"}
  end
end
```

I have a method in my controller file as

```
def autocomplete
  results = Univ.univ_name_matches(params[:term])   
  render :json => results, :callback => params[:callback]
end
```

and the view file is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: function(request,response) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/universities/autocomplete.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            term: request.term          
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var rows=[];
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                rows.push({data[i].univ_name), value:data[i].univ_name});
            }
        response(rows);         
        }
});
}           
});
</script>
<input name="univ_name" type ="text" id = "autocomplete">
```

I don't see anything happening in my view when I try to search for a value that is in the database

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I would try a couple of things to debug this: First, are you familiar with using `console.log();` to debug your JS? I would use it to display the value of `data` in your AJAX response. Also, you could either use `p params[:term]` or, preferably, use the `byebug` (or similar) gem to see what the parameters are that are hitting your `autocomplete` action. I'm not familiar with elasticsearch but these are common debugging tools that might help you. Good luck!

Comment: Is this correct `rows.push({data[i].univ_name), value:data[i].univ_name});` - looks like a bracket mismatch.